# Are pattern-printing questions on-topic or unwelcome here?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

Sometimes I can see questions about printing some patterns on the screen, but seems found many of them are not very well-received, eg these four now-deleted questions:

[C# nested loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711757)

[Half diamond pattern in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717734)

[How to write the code for this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713895)

[Up the Downstair- Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37860361)

Is this type of questions on topic here? If so, why they are not very well received (at least the questions above currently)?

Comment: I'm embarrassed to see four 10k+ users answer those questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pattern printing is really just a red herring here. The thing that makes those questions off topic is the fact that the author does not appear to have put in any effort. If they provided any code, they did not provide any explanation to why it doesn't work.

That means the problem is either a matter of:

- Figuring out what their code does and fixing it.
- Doing it for them.

It's not impossibly broad, but the community has made it quite clear before that the level of effort required to solve these questions is too high given the effort put into the question.

We see a lot of these questions, although they appear to mostly have calmed down during the summer, since most schools are out.

Answer (score 2):

They are not explicitly off-topic, but they are a breed of question which will not generally be well received. To make matters worse, they are often asked as a do-my-homework type question, and rarely show much research or effort.

Printing a pattern is actually a multi-step process, with several components that must be understood. A question asking how to print a specific pattern on its own would almost-certainly be too-broad.

The only case in which I can see such a question being on-topic, is in the form of a question seeking debugging help, which *are* on-topic, but only *if* a specific issue is being addressed. This close reason lists the requirements.

> Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

I'm afraid such questions that meet the minimum requirements are all-too rare. Even when such requirements are met, they are rarely interesting enough to be great questions, so being very well-received would still not be very likely.

Those you listed have all been closed, with entirely accurate close reasons.

Answer (score 1):

From my perspective, homework questions are both acceptable and welcome on the site, provided that they're at the same quality as any other question on here.

The problem with *these* questions is that they're *lazy*.  They don't show much effort or much of the problem solving aspect of it.  [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711757/up-the-downstair-python) (10k only) only barely showed any effort, and that's not something we want around on the site.

My opinion is that they're on-topic but they're pretty poor quality, so downvoting it would be the best option.  Users with the privilege can delete it once the question is closed (likely for not having an MCVE), but my preference would just be to downvote the content.  If nothing else, the Roomba will get it for us later.

Comment: This ^^^^. This is exactly the point that I tried to express the most when we deprecated the homework tag. We _should_ entertain questions that have seemingly odd, or silly constraints - provided that they're asked in the manner that we'd expect from any other question.